# Finding all possible complete pairings from a list in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I've got a single list of names, and I'd like to generate every possible combination, where every person on the list is paired uniquely, in a non-repeating way, using Google Sheets. The list of names is variable, and may occasionally be an odd number. 
So for example if I had four people, the list would look like this, only the numbers would be replaced with actual names.

```
(1,2)(3,4)

(1,3)(2,4)

(1,4)(2,3)
```

Once I have the complete list of combinations, I can sort it myself to find which ones have been least used before.

Answer (score 3):

Try python itertools. https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

```
import itertools
nameList = ['john', 'joe', 'jimmy', 'jack']

for name1, name2 in itertools.combinations( nameList, 2 ):
  print( '({}, {})'.format( name1, name2 ))
```

If you want both (name1, name2) and (name2, name1) try itertools.permuations

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A1:A4&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(A1:A4)), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(A1:A4&CHAR(9), COUNTA(A1:A4))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A1:A4&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(A1:A4)), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(A1:A4&CHAR(9), COUNTA(A1:A4))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0)), 
 "select Col2,Col3,Col4,Col7,Col8,Col12", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Thank all for your help. I think my query was lacking in detail. I was hoping for a table result, where each line was a thorough result of every person/string being paired with another string individually. 
I'm bad at coding, so I was inspired to do it in python, using a recursive function and a little math wizardry. I was able to make it accept a variable list and expand accordingly.

```
nameList = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
if(len(nameList) % 2 == 1):
    nameList.append(" ")
print(nameList)
length = len(nameList)
possible = 1

while length > 1:
    possible = possible*(length-1)
    length -= 2
def completeCombinations (List, line):
    BaseList = list(List)
    if (line % (len(List)-1) == 0):
        num = (len(List)-1)
    else:
        num = line % (len(List)-1)
    BaseList.remove(List[0])
    BaseList.remove(List[num])
    if(len(List) > 2):
        CurrentList = list(completeCombinations(BaseList, line))
        CurrentList.insert(0, List[num])
        CurrentList.insert(0, List[0])
    else:
        CurrentList = list(List)
    return CurrentList

i = 1
while i < possible:
    print completeCombinations(nameList, i+1)
    i += 1
```

And the results look pretty close what I'd hoped, if not necessarily pretty.

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', ' ']
['1', '3', '2', '5', '4', ' ']
['1', '4', '2', ' ', '3', '5']
['1', '5', '2', '3', '4', ' ']
['1', ' ', '2', '4', '3', '5']
['1', '2', '3', ' ', '4', '5']
['1', '3', '2', '4', '5', ' ']
['1', '4', '2', '5', '3', ' ']
['1', '5', '2', ' ', '3', '4']
['1', ' ', '2', '3', '4', '5']
['1', '2', '3', '5', '4', ' ']
['1', '3', '2', ' ', '4', '5']
['1', '4', '2', '3', '5', ' ']
['1', '5', '2', '4', '3', ' ']
['1', ' ', '2', '5', '3', '4']
```

Heartfelt thanks to anyone who can help me pretty it up and import the results into google sheets